# define constant in WordPress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have two questions which I don't understand in the WordPress plugin that I usually see.

1. what it means when this line of code written on the very top of each page in the plugin.

Does it mean if not define "ABSPATH" then exit?

2. what it means when this line of code written to define the constant?
   !defined('UT') && define('UT', PATH_SEPARATOR);?

Does it mean if not define 'UT' then define 'UT' for PATH_SEPARATOR?

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to include the code for 1st question: <?php !defined('ABSPATH') && exit; and 2nd question: !defined('UT') && define('UT', PATH_SEPARATOR);

Answer (score 0):

`if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;` is basically the de-facto way to prevent direct access to plugin files. It's a really simple security measure to prevent files from being directly queried by URL or by direct POST request.

The later one means exactly that, if the constant `UT` isn't defined, define it as the constant value for `PATH_SEPARATOR`, which is different on unix (`:`) and windows (`;`) based platforms.